# Aggregation in mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, mongoengine

I have tried to use aggregation in mongoengine but not getting any result. Initial code :

```
result = Review.objects.aggregate([{'$match': {'status': 'Remind'}}])
```

but I got error as :

```
command SON([('aggregate', u'review'), ('pipeline', [[{'$match': {'status': 'remind'}}]]), ('cursor', {})]) on namespace db_name.$cmd failed: exception: pipeline element 0 is not an object
```

After referring various [links](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/1252), I updated my code:

```
pipeline = [{ "$match": {'status': 'Remind' } }]
results = list(Review.objects.aggregate(*pipeline))
print 'result='+str(results)
```

Now, I am not getting any exception or error but result is still empty

```
result=[]
```

Here is my sample mongodb data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("599aaf826bc80b178a00ef1"),
    "timestamp" : "on Mar 19, 2017",
    "profile" : "Aditya Roy",
    "status" : "Remind",
    "created_on" : ISODate("2017-08-21T15:31:38.052Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("599aaf826bc80b178a00ef2"),
    "timestamp" : "on Mar 16, 2017",
    "profile" : "Shivam Singh",
    "status" : "Remind",
    "created_on" : ISODate("2017-08-21T15:31:38.778Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("599aaf836bc80b178a00ef3"),
    "timestamp" : "on Mar 13, 2017",
    "profile" : "Gautam Sharma",
    "status" : "Closed"
    "created_on" : ISODate("2017-08-21T15:31:39.526Z")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, the following is the right way to use mongoengine (working fine with mongoengine 0.18.0):
`Review.objects.aggregate({'$match': {'status': 'Remind'}})`

In fact, there is a difference in mongoengine `aggregate` interface, compared to pymongo's `aggregate` which takes a list